# how to pass inputed value to a method in java

Tags: java

let the user enter 2 numbers and pass the value to a method Sum() and Difference() and display the result

this is what have i done so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main
{
    static int num1,num2;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println ("First Number: ");
        num1 = reader.nextInt ();
        System.out.println ("Second Number: ");
        num2 = reader.nextInt ();
        Sum();
    }
    public static void Sum(int num1, int num2)
    {
        a = num1+num2;
        return System.out.println ("Sum: "+ a);
    }
}
```

expected output:

First Number: 3
Second Number: 4
Sum: 7

Comment: Look at the code you wrote. You called various methods already there. You are passing arguments to them. Do you really need other people to understand that your method expects 2 arguments ... that you already have? Just saying: you already HAVE all the things you need. Just connect the dots. The error message from the compiler also tells you whats wrong. The method you want to call expects 2 args, you are providing 0.

Comment: And unrelated, learn about java naming conventions. method names should go camelCase, and have a verb, so like `computeSum()` or maybe just `add()` instead of `Sum()`.

Comment: @GhostCat currently having 3 errors

Comment: Because you are throwing together things without understanding them. The println method for example has return type VOID, that means: it doesnt return anything. Thus your `return println(a)` is nonsensical. If you want to print a, then do it BEFORE the return. But please understand: this here isnt programming school were people give free tutoring to work with you through all the small problems you encounter when learning to program.

Comment: The real thing for you: work slowly. just write a few lines of code, **just enough** so that you think: this makes sense and should compile. Then: run the compiler. Very carefully read the error messages (they are REALLY good at telling you whats wrong). Fix the errors. If you dont understand them: put them into a search engine. Any such basic problem has been explained in the internet many many times. So: go searching. And then, when you fixed all errors, write some more code. And so on.

Comment: When asking for help with not working code, then also include the error message you encounter. See [mcve].

Comment: Finally: be careful about the variable you use. You declared num1 and num2 already as fields of your class. If you do that, your sum method does NOT need any parameter. Because it has access to the two fields in your class. But what you would really want: declare variables in the smallest scope possible. You could have local variables num1, num2 in your main method ... and **then** it makes sense that sum() takes 2 parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sum needs to take two arguments int num1 and int num2

In your main you need to call it in the following way:

```
sum(num1, num2)
```

Inside your sum function you use a variable a which is not typed. Java wants all its variables to have defined type.

```
int a = num1 + num2
```

will do the trick.

At last void functions do not have a return value.
If your goal is to solely print the number just write:

```
System.out.println ("Sum: "+ a);
```

instead of:

```
return System.out.println ("Sum: "+ a);
```

if you want to print and to return the number you need to change the signatur to:

```
public static int Sum(int num1, int num2)
```

and your body to:

```
System.out.println ("Sum: "+ a);
return a;
```

Comment: You should also mention the "bad" method name (no uppercase) and that mixing field names with method parameters is problematic.